# how to add a sound file in android program

Tags: android, media-player

I want  to write a program which can play a sound after clicking a button.
I have written the code below:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MediaPlayer btnSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnSound.start();
        }
    });
}

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

But I dont know where should I add this sound to my program
I have created a new folder in res named raw and added sound to  it but again this is an error in `MediaPlayer btnSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);`
can any one please help me

thanks alot for your attention in advance

Comment: Please put in stack trace from error log. Also what format is the sound? mp3, wav?

Comment: How big are your mp3-files? For soundfiles less than 1MB SoundPool is an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           mp.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't work. Even when I type "R." there is no suggestion match with raw. I think I have imported this mp3 file in wrong folder

Comment: The raw folder must me inside the res folder

Comment: can you post the logcat

Comment: Try putting the mp3 file in the assets folder and see if it works